# How to duplicate selected vertices using python script?

Tags: python, edit-mode, vertices

How to duplicate selected vertices using python script?

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate()
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? Does these 2 lines are sufficient alone, or do we need, before, to select something / be in some mode... etc.?

Comment: To answer @Polosson: you must be in Edit Mode, with the vertices you want duplicated selected.